# How to record "export as" as an action in Photoshop CC

Tags: action, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm using `Photoshop CC v20.0.7`, and I'm trying to record the `[file > export > "export as"]` as an action. When I hit `"record"` and try, nothing is recorded in my action sequence, even though the `jpg` is correctly saved in my folder. Other methods of `exporting` and saving `jpg/png` won't work for me as I'm using a `duotone` document with only 2 `pantone spot colors` channels. **Is there a way to export/save my duotone document into a picture (for preview purposes) AND have it recorded as an action/script?**

PS: The `"quick export as jpg"` is recorded in the actions, but has no effect when I run the script, so it doesn't seem a viable option.

Thank you!

Comment: `Export As...` uses Generator and can't be scripted unfortunately

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy so there is absolutely 0 way to automate a multichannel psd into jpg?

Comment: Could you convert it to an 8bit image first within an action or a script? I don't have much experience with multichannel psds, maybe you can upload an example?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Here's a link to an example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ckI-JVZnOjAkoBuMWJ_V_S70sNv7ef-h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com or photo.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the scripting listener plugin, that'll record menu actions that aren't typically recorded by the action recorder tool, although the output isn't easily readable.

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```js
saveAsJPG();
function saveAsJPG() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var tempDoc = documents.add(doc.width,doc.height,doc.resolution,doc.name);
    var docPath = documents[0].fullName
    placeImage(docPath);
    saveFile = new File("d:/"+documents[0].name.replace(/[.]...$/,""));
    saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
    saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
    saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
    saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
    saveOptions.quality = 10; 
    activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
    activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
function placeImage(imagePath) {
    var idPlc = charIDToTypeID( "Plc " ); 
    var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();  
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    desc11.putPath( idnull, new File(imagePath) );
    var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" ); 
    var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );   
    var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" ); 
    desc11.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );     
    var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();     
    var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );    
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );      
    desc12.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 );     
    var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );    
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );    
    desc12.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 0.000000 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
    desc11.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc12 );
    executeAction( idPlc, desc11, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try the scripting listener plugin :) But the script you provided doesn't work since the document cannot be converted to RGB (it's a 2 spot color multichannel document)

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. I suppose a workaround would be to quick make a temp document with the right color mode and place your working doc in there as a smart object. I updated the script in my answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to use Save As -> Jpeg. You get all the same options and they all record into the action.

Comment: save as jpeg doesnt seem to have any options - you cant specify the quality, colour profile, new resolution etc?

Comment: You sure can do quality (in the second dialogue that shows up) and it always uses the active profile. My workflow is to duplicate the original document, close the original, and then work with the duplicate. I put a "convert to profile" in my action, and if you want a different image size, you can do that beforehand as well ("image size"). This is of course not a perfect solution and it would be much better if Photoshop saved the export function to actions, but as a workaround this is the best you got.